# How do I add a BOM to all UTF-8 files in a project?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Current encoding is UTF-8 and I want to add BOM to all the files

Context: Windows 8 app certification toolkit throws following error, if BOM is not added:

File C:\x\y\z.js is not properly UTF-8 encoded. Re-save the file as UTF-8 (including Byte Order Mark).

Comment: ["The Unicode Standard neither requires nor recommends the use of the BOM for UTF-8. The presence of the UTF-8 BOM may cause interoperability problems with existing software that could otherwise handle UTF-8"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's probably worth explaining why you are trying to do what you're asking - it leads to better answers.

Comment: Also, adding a BOM is not the same as changing encoding, so the title of your question contradicts the body of your question.

Comment: @christofferHammarström: Yes, I understand that, but packaging windows 8 store app requires it. Windows 8 app certification toolkit fails your app giving errors like:

File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\x\y\z.js is not properly UTF-8 encoded. Re-save the file as UTF-8 (including Byte Order Mark).

I understand that the title is wrong, will try to change it

Comment: That's a pretty retarded requirement from Microsoft, given that everyone including The Unicode Standard recommends against it, but there you go then.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström: they claim that adding BOM increases the performance of the app significantly.

Comment: @user2135441: Yes, i saw. They should fix that bug, instead of complicating life for everybody else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDE like eclipse or netbeans, you can select all files and set the encoding.
Other option is open all files in text editor and change.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Idea and Visual Studio 2012.
Can't open in Netbeans as its not a java project

Comment: there's an option in intellij to choose the encoding that all files in project. about visual studio, I don't know.

Comment: Is there?? I couldn't find it. Could you tell me where is it??

Comment: Actually there is an option to change encoding, but it doesn't support UTF-8 with BOM.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is how I did it:

create a php file: addBOMtoFile.php and add the following line:

```
file_put_contents("some_new_file_name.js", "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("some_file_name.js"), "UTF-8", "UTF-8"));
```

C:\php>php addBOMtoFile.php