# Output .js files from GWT in UTF-8 encoding with BOM

Tags: maven, gwt, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I'm using the Javascript files outputted by GWT in a Windows 8.1 app, however as well as being UTF-8 encoded the files also need the `Byte Order Mark` at the start.

(See this question for why: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/dd352270-8790-4b48-8492-17a4a6875e99/why-the-utf8-with-bom-marker-requirement )

Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm building GWT using Maven.

Is there anything I can change in the Maven pom.xml file that will output the files encoded in UTF-8 with the BOM?

Or a change to GWT config file?

Thank you for your help, I've been trying to figure this one out all afternoon!

Comment: Java itself does not recognize the BOM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897876/reading-utf-8-bom-marker

Comment: I don't get why the BOM is needed. As far as I understand the Post, a BOM will just speedup some loadingtime.

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for letting me know about Java & BOMs. The BOM is needed for the same reason as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222182/how-do-i-add-a-bom-to-all-utf-8-files-in-a-project Basically to certify a Windows 8 app.

Comment: Currently I'm working on a .bat script that will add it to the files. A bit of a hack but hopefully it will do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this question in the future and wants an answer...

I couldn't find a way to do this with GWT, so I added some code to a `.bat` build script that runs.

Before running this script you will need to save an empty file (`filewithbom.txt`) that contains only the UTF-8 Byte Order Marker (`0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` if you're interested). This can be done by saving an empty file in Notepad, and being sure to set the encoding to UTF-8.

You will also want to change the `CHANGE_DIR` directory.

```
set OLD_DIR="%CD%"
set CHANGE_DIR="[PATH TO DIRECTORY WITH FILES TO CHANGE]"
set BOM_FILE="filewithbom.txt"
cd %CHANGE_DIR%
for /R %%f in (*.js, *.html) do (  
  type %BOM_FILE% >> tempfile.txt    
  type %%f >> tempfile.txt
  xcopy /Y tempfile.txt %%f
  del tempfile.txt
)
cd %OLD_DIR%
```

This loops through the `CHANGE_DIR` directory and it's subfolders, and adds the contents `filewithbom.txt` to the start of every file with a filename ending `.js` or `.html`.